# Javascript Logic Error Expose

Tags: javascript

I made the dumbest **javascript** mistake but it took me a while to actually realize.

Is there any programs or tools designed to "expose' bad **JS** logic like the one shown below?

```
function displayTime() {
    var systemTime = new Date();
    document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = systemTime;
    setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
}
```

Plz don't judge me by this code... my brain was elsewhere. |:

Comment: You mean creating an interval that calls the same function?

Comment: ....yes - is there a program that exposes such bad logic?

Comment: That's not always an error. You might have code like `if (some_condition) { clearInterval(timeInterval); timeInterval = setInterval(displayTime, 1000); }`

Comment: The set interval part was fine.. it's just the way I did it. My displayTime() was setting the interval every second, but then it calls itself! This means that the setInterval was multiplying.

Comment: I understand that. But what if you have an interval function that checks for some condition and then restarts itself with a different period?

Comment: The point is that there's no general rule that an interval function shouldn't set itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no general rule that a function called using `setInterval` shouldn't set the interval to itself. You could have code like this:

```
var lastPeriod = 1000;
var curPeriod = 1000;
var timer = setInterval(displayTime, curPeriod);

function displayTime() {
    document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = new Date();
    if (curPeriod != lastPeriod) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        lastPeriod = curPeriod;
        timer = setInterval(displayTime, curPeriod);
    }
}
```

There could then be an event listener somewhere that changes `curPeriod`, and the next time `displayTime` runs it will notice that it changed and update its period.

Comment: (: Good example! I couldn't think of a scenario where it makes sense for a function to setInterval itself.        Thx for your feedback. :D